# How does PCollection gets created by a runner

Tags: apache-beam

Similar to the code below get called internally from `Read` or `GroupBy` transform during expand. In terms of Beam code this will result in construction of an instance of `PCollection`. It is not apparent and clear what is actually being constructed by looking at the code as it is limited to just `new` operation. In terms of runner what does it mean by calling `new PCollection(...)`?

```
PCollection.createPrimitiveOutputInternal(
        input.getPipeline(),
        WindowingStrategy.globalDefault(),
        IsBounded.BOUNDED,
        ByteArrayCoder.of())
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Apache Beam programming [guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/):

> A PCollection represents a distributed data set that your Beam pipeline operates on. The data set can be bounded, meaning it comes from a fixed source like a file, or unbounded, meaning it comes from a continuously updating source via a subscription or other mechanism.

PCollection implements PValue, from its [document](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7e1aa0df191462d8b78f9233e3d872c7582461ef/sdks/python/apache_beam/pvalue.py#L79):

> Dataflow users should not construct PValue objects directly in their
> pipelines.

Think it in this way: when using the SDK building a pipeline, you are constructing a directed acyclic graph of nodes of PTransforms and edges of PCollections. In the DAG, a PCollection instance is abstract and represents an input/output of PTransform[s]. When the DAG is executed on a runner, the data of each PCollection can reside on multiple machines/VMs/workers. You cannot view the data until you materialize them through some IO transforms.

If internally in the SDK, you see `new PCollection(...)`, it builds the edge/node with necessary information that could later make sense to the runner when executing the DAG. A PCollection itself is not a data structure that holds data in memory.

Comment: I am looking for more runner specific behavior with respect to construction of the pcollection, not in terms of the SDK

Comment: Each runner is implemented differently. And some of the code is not even in the Beam repo. Your best bet is looking at https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/portability/ and how to create a runner at https://beam.apache.org/contribute/runner-guide/, then read the proto definition of runner / Fn API (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/model/fn-execution/src/main/proto/beam_fn_api.proto). But it all depends on the runner implementation to honor those contracts and implement them correctly.